# Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm, version

I'm trying to launch the `rails s` command and I get this error:

> Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1

Running `rvm list` I get:

```
rvm rubies 
ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ] 
\# => - current
\# =* - current && default 
\#  * - default
```

It seems like I don't have Ruby 2.0.0 installed but yet it says that I do.

I'll just run `rvm --default use 2.1.1` and it will fix it but whenever happens that I have to download the repo and start from scratch it keeps showing me that error.

Answer (score 3):

If you have ruby 2.1.1 installed and specified that version in your `Gemfile`, then try running the command using `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec rails s
```

That way, you will run the rails server in the context of your `Gemfile`.

If the above does not work, try installing/updating your bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

or

```
gem update bundler
```

You can also specify the ruby version (`2.1.1` or `2.0.0`) in a `.ruby-version` file in the top-level directory of your rails app.

Answer (score -1):

This is because somewhere in your Gemfile you have specified:

```
ruby '2.1.1'
```

If you remove above line from Gemfile you would stop getting this message. Else you can edit accordingly it to your Ruby version.